# Advertise This App Link Missing On Android Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, ads, server-error

The app is being displayed in the Android Market, but I just tried downloading it and got a server error. Here is how it looks on my Android Developers Account...

[image: http://webprogramming360.com/Beer-Counter/App_Not_Publishing.png]

The advertise link is missing and I can't download it from the market on my phone because I get "server error". Here is the app...

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.joeb.apps.beer.counter

Comment: "server error" Sounds like you have no internet / you have it already installed as dedbu. Happy crimbo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is not available for paid applications. In my experience the **Advertise Here** only shows for free apps. You could just go to http://www.admob.com/ and set up any advertisement through there.

And if you set up your developer account with example@gmail.com and then tried to download the app under the same email address, then you are supposed to get an error. If you got a "Server Error", though it would rarely mean there's something wrong with the app and rather mean something with the phone or the gmail association on the Market. What I'm saying is that I'm sure others will still be able to download it.